# Using a JSON file as database

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm writing a small game on react native and I'm using a json file to store the levels.

Example code:

```
let levelData = require("./levels.json"); // this loads once when app opens
engine.load(levelData[23]); // Load level 23
```

The json file is about 7 megabytes. I'm just using the file to read data, not writing or other operations. My question is if this method has any bad effects on the app (like performance etc.) and are there any better methods I can use?

Comment: check this https://www.quora.com/Can-I-just-use-JSON-instead-of-creating-a-database

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size and frequency of CRUD operation, Using a file, you have to rewrite the entire file again and again.
Also a database can survive any power failure and other disasters, but a file cannot.
If the data is small and you don't access it frequently you can use a file.
But if the data is important, I will definitely recommend you to use a database. you could use Joint Database Technology if you want a document type file based database. you can dump, backup and restore them.